# Listen for TileOpened event in background task?

Tags: microsoft-band

How do I go about triggering a background task to occur when a user opens the tile on the band while the phone app is suspended?

Alternatively, how would I make my background task constantly listen for the TileOpened event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows (Phone) 8.1, background tasks cannot be triggered by ad-hoc input from a Band. To receive events the application must be running, either in the foreground or background, with an active connection to a Band, and with a subscription to a Tile event.

Background tasks on Windows (Phone) can only be triggered at most every 15 or 30 minutes, which means that they are not generally suitable for polling for Tile events as it's unlikely they will be running at the time the user opens a Tile.

Comment: That's a real shame, and it seems like a huge limitation. Hopefully this is something the Band team will consider adding in future SDK updates. Thank you for your answer.
Edit: I'd upvote your score but apparently I don't have enough rep.

Comment: It's actually less about the Band SDK than it is about the Windows 8.1 platform itself and the limitations it imposes on communication between applications (for security purposes) as well as its restrictions on the frequency of background task execution (for battery life purposes).  Windows 10 eases some of those limitations which then allows, theoretically, some more interesting scenarios with the Band.  (The Band itself and Band SDK would likely still require updates to take advantage of them, however.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing that!

Comment: I really hope that this is going to happen! A bunch of new apps would be possible... THIS and actionable notifications of W10M being sent to the Band... :)

Comment: Band is dead, so... this definitely isn't going to happen :(